# uv pack islands to fit/cover all area

Tags: uv

I have uv layout like in the image. I just want to force it to occupy the empty area in the right (Right now it's only cover the left area) . How can do this ? but keep the overal rough shape without making all become square. So basically just like to scale it X direction but do it automatically to fit the space.

Thanks

blend file :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18DxOHq_wxzXHrv7gVvsswGNwl8D-4Lwe?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Have you tried Scale to Bound? The option is available just after your unwrap, on the bottom of the left menu (activated with T when you are in 3D view)

Comment: @moonboots i can't find 'scale to bound'. There's similar setting but not in unwarp. It's in smart uv project , called "stretch to UV bound". But using smart uv project , it  will break the island, i'm not getting a single continuous island.

Comment: so I guess you've tried wall the options of Unwrap? Conformal instead of Angle Based and unclick the Fill Holes option?

Comment: @moonboots i update my post , i've included the link to the .blend file. Pls check it out.

Comment: if you go in top ortho view, enter in Edit mode, press U > Project from View, and click on the Scale to Bounds option on the bottom of the T menu, you don't get what you want?

Comment: Great , that's what i'm looking for . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Top Ortho view, enter in Edit mode, select the whole mesh, press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project From View*, and click on the *Scale to Bounds* option on the bottom of the left menu (displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>), or choose directly *Project From View (Bounds)*.

[image]